# #text at the begging of every page, before the main content block

Tags: html

If you check my website ([website](https://kavitacijabeograd.com)) you can see the problem right away, I can't locate that #text anywhere ...
I hope someone can help me with this frustrating problem I faced!

Don't know what else to say hopefully this is enough.

Thank you in advance !

[image]

Comment: How are you getting the two Google Fonts into the site?  It's not putting them in the head, so my first guess would be that whatever/wherever those fonts are being added, that's probably the culprit.

Comment: I found it man ! It was in custom headers and footers where I added my fonts ! thanks alot !

Comment: You shouldn't be adding your fonts that way either, you should enqueue them like you would any other script. I'll post an answer.

Comment: I'm not  sure how to add them or any other script the right way...

Comment: See answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we know that the '#' was accidentally added when you were including the custom fonts from Google that's addressed, but as per the comments, here's the correct way to add these fonts so that you're not dropping them in your custom header. You want to place them in the head instead so you have to enqueue them.  You'd add this to your functions.php file.  The 'xx' at the end of each needs to be replaced, make that match your theme version.

```
function lilika_fonts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'arvo-font', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo|Dancing+Script|Josefin+Sans|Oswald|Pacifico&display=swap', array(), 'xx' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'kaushan-font', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kaushan+Script&display=swap', array(), 'xx' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'lilika_fonts' );
```

Comment: What should xx become ?

Comment: The XX should be the version number of your theme.

Comment: What if I update the version, do I need to adjust on that spot ?

Comment: You would.  I use a method where I establish a global $themeversion variable in the functions.php file and then just reference that throughout the theme anywhere so need to include the version number.   I can post an answer later this afternoon evening if you want.